# Transformation of a point with GDAL

Tags: gdal, georeferencing, gdalwarp, gdal-translate

I know the place where the image was captured and I've made pixel to lat-lon correspondences (GCPs).

After running the following GDAL commands a .tif file is created.

```
gdal_translate -of GTiff -gcp {gcp_1} -gcp {gcp_2} ... -gcp  {gcp_n} "/path/to/image.png" "/tmp/image.png"
gdalwarp -r near -order 3 -co COMPRESS=None -dstalpha -t_srs EPSG:4326 "/tmp/image.png" "/path/to/image_modified.tif"
```

Now I want to find **the correspondence between each pixel** of "/path/to/image.png" image and "/path/to/image_modified.tif" georeferenced image.

I have searched a lot but I couldn't find anything that can solve my problem. All that I found was the way to find the lat-lon coordinate of each pixel in "/path/to/image_modified.tif" image.

Comment: I do not believe that you can get that information from the GDAL API. You should study the source code and the resampling algorithms and make the program to print some interim report about what is is going to do for the source pixels.